# How to add sub menu in front page for the product category in prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

I want to add sub menu for my category menu for my main menu displayed in the front landing page as shown here [image]

This is my category

[image]

When I hover the Category Ticket I must be able to see three submenus 
1)Buy ticket  (link to the product page which will be always dynamic page)
2)See winners ( a cms page )
3)Check offers ( a cms page)

Category are displayed by adding category 
Is there any option to do submenu for category  from the  prestashop 1.6 back end

Answer (score 0):

You should install `blocktopmenu` module. Already contained in Prestashop official installation. This module allows you to create submenus. All you'll have to do is to style it with css.

Answer (score 0):

Becouse I cant comment below Florian Lemaitre post I write here, module bloctopmenu didn't have options to create submenu, it is create automaticaly submenu only for category who contains subcategories. If somebody need create some custom submenus containing for example cms page or add home icon he must use third party module.